# How to reproduce the gradient effect in the 'Find My iPhone' icon?

Tags: icon, gradient, iphone

[image]

How to make this icon in Illustrator/Photoshop or any other software for that matter?

Comment: Bit too lazy to make a full-fledged answer right now but this article should point you in the right direction: http://www.astutegraphics.com/blog/how-to-apply-a-gradient-fill-to-strokes-in-adobe-illustrator-cs5-and-earlier/

Answer (score 7):

The gradient is a simple angle gradient. It is the third option on gradient tools on photoshop, however to get it spot on, you may have to tweak the color stops, rather than just using a standard two point gradient.

Here is a quick comparison using the above method. As you can see, it's almost exactly the same:
[image: comparison]